# swift reading array on interval shows index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a page that show messages from a database. The message is getting loaded as it should but when i try to reload it to show the new messages after a interval of one minute i get the message out of range. It looks like the array is empty for some reason. I have read so many of the solutions but non of them explain what is happening in my code.

This is the complete code.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class LeftSideViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var answerPMTapped: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var senderProfileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var BodyMessage: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var TitleMessage: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalKm: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ranking: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalCollected: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var euroSign: UILabel!



    var MessageId = [String]()
    var MessageSender = [String]()
    var MessageReceiver = [String]()
    var MessageBody = [String]()
    var MessageTime = [String]()
    var MessageDate = [String]()
    var MessageStatus = [String]()
    var MessageTitle = [String]()
    var SenderUsername = [String]()
    var ReplyMessageId = [String]()

    var T_message_Title:String!

    var menuItems:[String] = ["Home","Profiel", "Goede Doelen", "Berichten", "Verstuur bericht", "Instellingen","Uitloggen"];

    var menuImage: [String] = ["home", "profile", "charity", "message", "reply", "settings", "logout"]

    var urlString = String()

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
        load_message()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        get_user_data()
        get_my_message_list()

        /* if (TitleMessage != nil){
            var title_convert = MessageTitle[1]
            var message_convert = MessageBody[1]
            TitleMessage.text = title_convert
            BodyMessage.text = message_convert
        } else {
            BodyMessage.text = "Er zijn geen berichten op dit moment."
        } */

        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var userEmail = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as! String

        let newUsername = userEmail.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "")
        let NewUserName = newUsername.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("@", withString: "")
        let imgString = NewUserName

        var urlString = "xxxxxxxx/profile/image/\(imgString).jpg"

        euroSign.hidden = true

        if (totalCollected != nil) {
            euroSign.hidden = false
        }

        self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
        self.profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true;

        load_profile_image(urlString)
        var reload_messages =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60.0, target: self, selector: Selector("message_Reloader"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }

    func message_Reloader(){
        self.MessageId.removeAll()
        self.MessageSender.removeAll()
        self.MessageReceiver.removeAll()
        self.MessageBody.removeAll()
        self.MessageTime.removeAll()
        self.MessageDate.removeAll()
        self.MessageStatus.removeAll()
        self.MessageTitle.removeAll()
        self.SenderUsername.removeAll()
        self.ReplyMessageId.removeAll()
        get_my_message_list()
        load_message()
    }

    func load_profile_image(urlString: String){
        var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.profileImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                println(imgURL)
            }
        })
    }



    func get_user_data(){
        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var userEmail = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as! String

        let url = NSURL(string:"xxxxxx/fetch-user-profile.php")
        let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        // set Content-Type in HTTP header
        let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
        let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
        NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)

        // set data
        var dataString = "username=\(userEmail)"
        let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

        // set content length
        //NSURLProtocol.setProperty(requestBodyData.length, forKey: "Content-Length", inRequest: request)

        var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
        var error: NSError? = nil
        let dataReply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)


        if(dataReply != nil){
            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
            {

        var results = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataReply!, options: nil, error: &error) as! NSDictionary

        NSLog("PostData: %@",dataReply!);

        NSLog("ResultData: %@",results);

        var jsonOutput = JSON(data: dataReply!)


        totalKm.text = jsonOutput["total_km"].stringValue
        totalCollected.text = jsonOutput["collected"].stringValue
        ranking.text = jsonOutput["rank"].stringValue
        profileName.text = jsonOutput["username"].stringValue

            } else {

                println( "Fetching data failed.")


            }

        } else {

            println( "Fetching data failed.")
        }

    }

        func load_message(){
            println("\(MessageBody[0])")
            var messagebody = MessageBody[0]
            var messagetitle = MessageTitle[0]

            var messagesender = MessageSender[0]

            let newUsername = messagesender.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "")
            let NewUserName = newUsername.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("@", withString: "")
            let imgString = NewUserName

            var urlString = "xxxxxxxxx/profile/image/\(imgString).jpg"

            self.senderProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.senderProfileImage.frame.size.width / 2;
            self.senderProfileImage.clipsToBounds = true;

            var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    self.senderProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    println(imgURL)
                }
            })


            if (messagetitle.isEmpty){
                BodyMessage.text = "Er zijn geen berichten op dit moment."

            }
            else {
                TitleMessage.text = messagetitle
                BodyMessage.text = messagebody
            }
    }

    @IBAction func answerPM(sender: AnyObject) {

        var messageid = MessageId[0]
        var messagesender = MessageSender[0]
        var messagereceiver = MessageReceiver[0]
        var senderusername = SenderUsername[0]
        var replymessageid = ReplyMessageId[0]

        // send over the orignal message so we can use that info to show the message again when they click the back button
        var messagedate = MessageDate[0]
        var messagebody = MessageBody[0]
        var messagetitle = MessageTitle[0]
        var messagetime = MessageTime[0]
        var messagesendeR = MessageSender[0]


        var centerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("answerMessage") as! answerMessageView

        centerViewController.MessageId2 = messageid
        centerViewController.MessageSender2 = messagesender
        centerViewController.MessageReceiver2 = messagereceiver
        centerViewController.SenderUsername2 = senderusername
        centerViewController.ReplyMessageId2 = replymessageid
        println("sender username: \(senderusername) reply message id: \(replymessageid)")
        centerViewController.A_messagedate = messagedate
        centerViewController.A_messagebody = messagebody
        centerViewController.A_messagetitle = messagetitle
        centerViewController.A_messagetime = messagetime
        centerViewController.A_messagesendeR = messagesendeR


        var centerNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = centerNavController
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func viewAllMessages(sender: AnyObject) {
        var userProfiles = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("messagesList") as! MessagesView

        var userProfileNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userProfiles)

        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = userProfileNav
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func markMGSRead(sender: AnyObject) {
    }





    func get_my_message_list(){

        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var receiverEmail = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as! String


        println("userEmail: \(receiverEmail)")


        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "xxxxxxxxxx/user/fetchmymessages.php")!)
        //let urlEncodedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        var postData = "receiveremail=\(receiverEmail)"
        request.HTTPBody = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        NSLog("data: \(request)")
        var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, innerError) in
            NSLog("response: \(response)")
            let json = JSON(data: data)

            if json != nil {

                let mysocialArray = json.arrayValue

                NSLog("\(json)")

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    for mysociallist in mysocialArray
                    {
                        let messageId = mysociallist["message_id"].stringValue
                        let sender = mysociallist["sender"].stringValue
                        let receiver = mysociallist["receiver"].stringValue
                        let messageBody = mysociallist["message"].stringValue
                        let time = mysociallist["time"].stringValue
                        let date = mysociallist["date"].stringValue
                        let messageStatus = mysociallist["message_read"].stringValue
                        let messagesubject = mysociallist["message_title"].stringValue
                        let senderusername = mysociallist["sender_username"].stringValue
                        let replymessageid = mysociallist["reply_message_id"].stringValue


                        println( "message id: \(messageId)" )
                        println( "message sender: \(sender)" )
                        self.MessageId.append(messageId)
                        self.MessageSender.append(sender)
                        self.MessageReceiver.append(receiver)
                        self.MessageBody.append(messageBody)
                        self.MessageTime.append(time)
                        self.MessageDate.append(date)
                        self.MessageStatus.append(messageStatus)
                        self.MessageTitle.append(messagesubject)
                        self.SenderUsername.append(senderusername)
                        self.ReplyMessageId.append(replymessageid)


                    }


                })

            }else {

                var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                alertView.title = "Berichten ophalen mislukt"
                alertView.message = "Er is een fout opgetreden, daardoor kunnen de berichten niet tonen."
                alertView.delegate = self
                alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alertView.show()
            }

        }


        task.resume()

    }// end of get my message list





    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return menuItems.count;
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        var mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as! MyCustomTableViewCell

        mycell.menuItemLabel?.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]

        mycell.menuItemImage?.image = UIImage(named: menuImage[indexPath.row])

        return mycell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        switch(indexPath.row)
        {

        case 0:

            var centerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("memberArea") as! userOverview

            var centerNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = centerNavController
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)



            break;

        case 1:

            var userProfiles = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("userProfile") as! userProfile

            var userProfileNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userProfiles)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = userProfileNav
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

            break;

        case 2:

            var userProfiles = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("userProfile") as! userProfile

            var userProfileNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userProfiles)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = userProfileNav
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

            break;




        case 3:

            var userProfiles = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("messagesList") as! MessagesView

            var userProfileNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userProfiles)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = userProfileNav
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

            break;

        case 4:

            var userProfiles = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("answerMessage") as! answerMessageView

            var userProfileNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userProfiles)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = userProfileNav
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

            break;

        case 5:

            var userProfiles = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("answerMessage") as! answerMessageView

            var userProfileNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userProfiles)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = userProfileNav
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

            break;

        case 6:


            let appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain!)

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggin_out", sender: self)

            break;

        default:

            println("\(menuItems[indexPath.row]) is selected");

        }
    }
}
```

this is the full code but the part that is giving the error is when the following is being called,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var reload_messages =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60.0, target: self, selector: Selector("message_Reloader"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }

    func message_Reloader(){
        self.MessageId.removeAll()
        self.MessageSender.removeAll()
        self.MessageReceiver.removeAll()
        self.MessageBody.removeAll()
        self.MessageTime.removeAll()
        self.MessageDate.removeAll()
        self.MessageStatus.removeAll()
        self.MessageTitle.removeAll()
        self.SenderUsername.removeAll()
        self.ReplyMessageId.removeAll()
        get_my_message_list()
        load_message()
    }
```

i have left out a little part of viewdidload to make it not too long.

I am not a pro so i can really use some help here to figure out how to called the function and store it in the array so i can show the new message.

Hope some one can give me some code examples or can point me into the right  direction, i am really stuck here and it keeps crashing my app.

Thanks

Comment: You should try showing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question instead of all this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) in your code: `get_my_message_list()` method is asynchronous, so `load_message()` can be called before `get_my_message_list()` is completed. In `load_message()` you're trying to access array members at index 0:

```
...    
var messagebody = MessageBody[0]
var messagetitle = MessageTitle[0]
...
```

And that's the problem: those arrays can be empty (if `get_my_message_list()` still haven't updated them).

Comment: Ok, i see yes, so in my case i should make the function synchonous so it is getting called and completed before the second function is called. Do i get that correct.

Comment: No, in your case making the function synchronous would be wrong - since you'd be blocking the main thread while network call is executing.

Comment: I would add a callback parameter to get_my_message_list() that should be called after it completes (and call load_message from there). Please see http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/how-to-use-blocks-as-callbacks as example.

Comment: sorry, but then i am lost, what other options do i have to make sure one function is being total executed before the other starts. thanks for your help.

Comment: You should learn about using blocks. More links: http://www.appcoda.com/objective-c-blocks-tutorial/ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html